# MySQL upgrade5.5 to 5.6, date code broken

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5, mysqlupgrade

I'm facing an issue after upgarde MySQL from v5.5 to 5.6,
I have copied the DB from 5.5 to 5.6 version, all seems working fine except date functions:
**example:**
`select count(*) from mybooking_testing.testtable where NOW() NOT BETWEEN testtable.orderDateFrom AND testtable.orderDateTO and testtable.id = 176544` returning 1 in MySQL5.5 while 0 in MySQL 5.6.
*Note: Both orderDateFrom and orderDateTO are null*

This issue is breking my whole code in production and wanted to fix it by MySQL only not by code.

I have tried SQL_MODE workaround set SQL_MODE ="" with no success.

any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: only one row in this testtable that is 176544 NULL NULL

Comment: How did you update your database? Try to use a `mysql_dump`.

Comment: used that only, I guess issue with only date only when use NOT BETWEEN  function, it returns 1 in old v5.5 while same query return 0 in new v5.6 @Solarflare

Comment: Comparisons with `null` always return false. `now() not between and date1 and date2` translate to `(now() < date1 or now() > date2)`. Only if at least one of these is not null, you get `true`, mysql before 5.6 did it wrong. If you cannot fix your code, you can update your dates to `0000-00-00`  instead of `null`, and change the column to `not null default '0000-00-00'` (or a valid date, depending on your sql mode). But it might have some effects to other parts of your code where you rely on the opposite behaviour. Safest way is to fix your code.

Comment: @Solarflare is there any way to deprecate the v5.6 feature so it point to 5.5 and solve the issue because code fix will be big work.

Comment: 'select count(*) from mybooking_testing.testtable where NOW() NOT BETWEEN testtable.orderDateFrom AND testtable.orderDateTO and testtable.id = 176544' returning 1 in MySQL5.5 while 0 in MySQL 5.6 even removing NOT and wrting BETWEEN instead. Note: Both orderDateFrom and orderDateTO are null

Comment: I don't think that behaviour can be simulated in 5.6., but `between` is probably the only problem (direct comparisons like `>= null` were `false` even in 5.5), so check your code for `between` and replace the dates with something like e.g. `coalesce(start_date,'0000-00-00')` or add `or start_date is null and end_date is null`, this might be the fastest fix.

Comment: @Solarflare can't we set this in MySQL only, any option ? because getting in the code and change there is big process task here.

Comment: I don't think so. This might have been related to [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78832) (your `NOT` making the `0` into a `1`, while `NOT` to `null`-result would still be `null`/`false`)  and got fixed, there is usually never an option to revert this. As I said, it might work to automatically set `null` values to `0000-00-00`, but I don't know what other consequences that would have in your code (e.g. `null <= now()` would have been false (or rather `null`) before, while `'0000-00-00' <= now()` would then be true).